# Copy/assign a Pandas dataframe based on their name in a for loop

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, loops

I am relatively new with python - and I am struggling to do the following:

I have a set of different data frames, with sequential naming (df_i), which I want to access in a for loop based on their name (with an string), how can I do that? e.g.

```
df_1 = pd.read_csv('...')
df_2 = pd.read_csv('...')
df_3 = pd.read_csv('...')
....

n_df = 3
for i in range(len(n_df)):
    df_namestr= 'df_' + str(i+1)
    # --------------------- 
    df_temp = df_namestr 
    # --------------------- 
    # Operate with df_temp. For i+1= 1, df_temp should be df_1
```

Kind regards,

DF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
for n in range(1, n_df+1):
    df_namestr = f"df_{n}"
    df_tmp = locals().get(df_namestr)
    if not isinstance(df_tmp, pd.DataFrame):
        continue
    print(df_namestr)
    print(df_tmp)
```

Refer to the documentation of [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) to know more.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I am looking for! Thanks @Corralien. 

But the data frame names are a little bit more complicated than the example I gave, and I would like to create the string outside the locals() function.

But if I define a string inside the loop called 'df_name', how can I use it inside locals().get(??).

`
for n in range(1, n_df+1):
    df_name = 'df'+str(i)
    df_tmp = locals().get(f"df_name") 
    if not isinstance(df_tmp, pd.DataFrame):
        continue
    print(df_tmp)

`

Comment: I updated my answer. Is it what you expect now?

Comment: Exactly! Thanks :D

Comment: Hi again @Corralien. Is there any reason why this code `df_tmp = locals().get(df_namestr)` wouldn't work inside a function?

Comment: Yes there is a very good reason. locals() is the dictionary that refers local symbols in the current scope (your function) however your dataframe variables are not declared in your function. You have to replace `locals()` by `globals()`

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! It is working now inside functions.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be better to approach the accessing of multiple dataframes by reading them into a list?

You could put all the csv files required in a subfolder and read them all in.  Then they are in a list and you can access each one as an item in that list.

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'/Users/myUsername/Documents/subFolder'
csv_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

dfs = []

for filename in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    dfs.append(df)

print(len(dfs))

print(dfs[1].head())
```